# How to access the downloads folder?

Tags: android, apk

I am trying to install an `apk` from the downloads directory of my device. My hard coded solution works like a charm-

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "update.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

but as soon as I change it to

```
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "update.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

I get parsing the package error. What am I doing wrong????

Comment: can you paste your logcat error ?

Comment: I see slashes in the first version. Are you sure they're taken care of in the second?

Comment: @m you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value returned by

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

is **/storage/emulated/0/Download** its missing a '/' at the end. Your path should be '/update.apk'

You need to use it as follows:

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/update.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```